# How to manage database for an application made for different regional offices?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a Windows application that connects to a SQL Server 2005 database using ADO.NET.

I have the server placed in Bangalore. The application needs to be used in Chicago as well. When I query the database from a Chicago PC it is 100 times slower, whereas when I remote desktop to a Bangalore it is extremely fast.

I am looking for some options through which I can keep the database maintained in a way that the data is kept updated from users in Bangalore and Chicago and at the same all the users get the same speed.

Comment: I once worked for a large corporate with a similar problem. Management were so obsessed with the idea that everyone should have the same speed of access that they decided that the right solution was to site the server midway between the two offices. Everyone did indeed get the same speed of access: slow. By that logic, move your server to London. More usefully, start by optimising your database queries, looking to minimise the amount of data passed across the network.

Answer (score 0):

Minimise amount of data passed across the network, as Mike W suggested;
Minimise the number of transactions for each operation (e.g. if there are 5 updates to perform, put them in one call, not 5 round-trips, when appropriate);
Depending on the usage (reading intensive? writing intensive? both?), and whether users need confirmation of updated data immediately, some operations can be performed in the background or async or using replication.

Comment: Yes I am working on optimizing the query execution. Apart from that I also need to look into matters such as what if the server stops for some reason? Should I not have alternative? I read some articles on database Peer to peer replication and other related things. What are your thoughts on these?

Comment: Nivedita, from your description it seems having a central database somewhere as well as a local cache in each office might suit your needs, assuming "server stops" is a valid potential problem.

Comment: hi Xeon, which is the way in which we can achieve to have a Central database with Caches in each office? is there any architecture you can refer me?

Comment: Hi Nivedita, last time I did it was quite some time ago when I did it semi-manually (having the same database everywhere with CDC turned on, and programmatically sync the detected changes), I am sure there are ways much better than this.